# MATLAB Use contains function within an IF statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a cell array, strings of months in MATLAB.  I am using the contains() function to determine if 'Ju' is in the string, along with an if statement, and if the statement is true, then delete 'Ju.'  But I am getting an error.
The error is:
Undefined function or variable 'a'.

Error in Untitled (line 4)
if a == contains(months, pattern)

```
pattern = 'Ju';
months = {'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'};

if a == contains(months, pattern)
    a = regexprep(months, 'Ju', '')
end
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a before testing it:

```
>> a = contains(months, pattern)

a =

  1×4 logical array

  1   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

For your example, you don't even need an if statement. [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) can handle it all for you:

```
>> pattern = 'Ju';
>> months = {'June', 'July', 'August', 'September'};
>> a = regexprep(months, pattern, '')

a =

  1×4 cell array

    'ne'    'ly'    'August'    'September'
```